# Insert a 3x3 2D array into a 9x9 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I need a Java function that takes a 2D 3x3 array and puts it into the center of a 2D 9x9 array. For example, the 3x3 array should look like this:

```
{{1,2,3},
 {4,5,6},
 {7,8,9}}
```

and the resulting 9x9 array should look like this:

```
{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},    < OLD|NEW >   {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},                   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},                   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},                   {0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},                   {0,0,0,4,5,6,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},                   {0,0,0,7,8,9,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},                   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},                   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}                   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: SO is not a code-authoring service of course.  What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
       array9x9[y+3][x+3] = array3x3[y][x];
```

Answer (score 1):

Two nested loops for the two coordinates, copy `(x, y)` into `(x+3, y+3)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an offset of 3 to copy elements:

```
int[][] res = new int[9][9];
for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int j = 3; j < 6; j++) {
        res[i][j] = arr[i - 3][j - 3];
    }
}
```